# Forms not working properly

Tags: microphone, text, input

I am Website Designer. I created an input text box through Blue Fish HTML Editor. But when I previewed in Firefox it is showing overlapped to next column. But in windows same browser is showing correctly. I am using lower version of Firefox in windows. In other browsers like Google Chrome, Safari, Opera etc its alignment is not properly showing compared to that in windows.

I connected a microphone on my system but it is not working but in windows it is working well.

Please give me a solution for this.

Regards,
Roney Wilson C

Answer (score 0):

That is a very vague issue you may need to include a snippet of your code to better illustrate the issue. It may just be that the box is drawn differently in the UI and you may just need to change the size. If you need 2 different sizes you would have to make a page for linux users and a page for windows users, or a redesign that accommodates both.

As for your microphone if it is a 3.5mm style you may need to configure the settings. By typing in the unity search box "Sound" and click Sound. In the sound settings under the input tab it should have your microphone input and the options.